# Ajax and PHP powered drop down list wont work in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu, onchange

Hi there I am having a problem with an ajax script in IE, it seems to work fine in all other browsers.  I am trying to re-write a drop down list to display a different price range depending on whether a user is looking to rent or looking to buy, here is how I've tackled it

function in header section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPrice(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getprice.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This is the HTML code that makes the table:

```
<table>
<form method="GET" action="search_results.php">
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="type" style="width:120px">
            <option selected="selected" value="residential">residential</option>
            <option value="commercial">commercial</option>
            <option value="business">business</option>
            <option value="student">student &amp; sharers</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="offered" style="width:120px" onchange="showPrice(this.value)">
            <option selected="selected" value="for_sale">for sale</option>
            <option value="to_let">to let</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="area"  style="width:120px">
            <option selected="selected" value="any">any area</option>
            <?php 
                $sql="select * from areas;";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);

                while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $area=$data['area'];
                    echo "<option value='$area'>$area</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="txtHint">
    <td>
        <select name='minprice' style="width:120px">
            <option selected='selected' value=''>min price</option>
            <option value='50000'>&pound;50,000</option>
            <option value='75000'>&pound;75,000</option>
            <option value='100000'>&pound;100,000</option>
            <option value='125000'>&pound;125,000</option>
            <option value='150000'>&pound;150,000</option>
            <option value='175000'>&pound;175,000</option>
            <option value='200000'>&pound;200,000</option>
            <option value='250000'>&pound;250,000</option>
            <option value='300000'>&pound;300,000</option>
            <option value='400000'>&pound;400,000</option>
            <option value='500000'>&pound;500,000</option>
            <option value='750000'>&pound;750,000</option>
            <option value='1000000'>&pound;1,000,000</option>
            <option value='1500000'>&pound;1,500,000</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name='maxprice' style="width:120px">
            <option selected='selected' value=''>max price</option>
            <option value='50000'>&pound;50,000</option>
            <option value='75000'>&pound;75,000</option>
            <option value='100000'>&pound;100,000</option>
            <option value='125000'>&pound;125,000</option>
            <option value='150000'>&pound;150,000</option>
            <option value='175000'>&pound;175,000</option>
            <option value='200000'>&pound;200,000</option>
            <option value='250000'>&pound;250,000</option>
            <option value='300000'>&pound;300,000</option>
            <option value='400000'>&pound;400,000</option>
            <option value='500000'>&pound;500,000</option>
            <option value='750000'>&pound;750,000</option>
            <option value='1000000'>&pound;1,000,000</option>
            <option value='1500000'>&pound;1,500,000</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="bedrooms" style="width:120px">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Bedrooms</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5 or more</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

and this is the php file that decides whether to echo the lover price rang or rhe upper price range:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

if($q=="to_let")
{
<td>
    <select name='minprice' style='width:120px'>
        <option selected='selected' value=''>min price</option>
        <option value='250'>&pound;250</option>
        <option value='500'>&pound;500</option>
        <option value='750'>&pound;750</option>
        <option value='1000'>&pound;1000</option>
        <option value='1250'>&pound;1250</option>
        <option value='1500'>&pound;1500</option>
        <option value='2000'>&pound;2000</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select name='maxprice' style='width:120px'>
        <option selected='selected' value=''>max price</option>
        <option value='250'>&pound;250</option>
        <option value='500'>&pound;500</option>
        <option value='750'>&pound;750</option>
        <option value='1000'>&pound;1000</option>
        <option value='1250'>&pound;1250</option>
        <option value='1500'>&pound;1500</option>
        <option value='2000'>&pound;2000</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select name='bedrooms' style='width:120px'>
        <option selected='selected' value=''>Bedrooms</option>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5 or more</option>
    </select>
</td>
PRICE;
}
else
{
    $my_string = <<<PRICE
    <td>
        <select name='minprice' style='width:120px'>
            <option selected='selected' value=''>minimum price</option>
            <option value='50000'>&pound;50,000</option>
            <option value='75000'>&pound;75,000</option>
            <option value='100000'>&pound;100,000</option>
            <option value='125000'>&pound;125,000</option>
            <option value='150000'>&pound;150,000</option>
            <option value='175000'>&pound;175,000</option>
            <option value='200000'>&pound;200,000</option>
            <option value='250000'>&pound;250,000</option>
            <option value='300000'>&pound;300,000</option>
            <option value='400000'>&pound;400,000</option>
            <option value='500000'>&pound;500,000</option>
            <option value='750000'>&pound;750,000</option>
            <option value='1000000'>&pound;1,000,000</option>
            <option value='1500000'>&pound;1,500,000</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select name='maxprice' style='width:120px'>
        <option selected='selected' value=''>maximum price</option>
        <option value='50000'>&pound;50,000</option>
        <option value='75000'>&pound;75,000</option>
        <option value='100000'>&pound;100,000</option>
        <option value='125000'>&pound;125,000</option>
        <option value='150000'>&pound;150,000</option>
        <option value='175000'>&pound;175,000</option>
        <option value='200000'>&pound;200,000</option>
        <option value='250000'>&pound;250,000</option>
        <option value='300000'>&pound;300,000</option>
        <option value='400000'>&pound;400,000</option>
        <option value='500000'>&pound;500,000</option>
        <option value='750000'>&pound;750,000</option>
        <option value='1000000'>&pound;1,000,000</option>
        <option value='1500000'>&pound;1,500,000</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select name='bedrooms' style='width:120px'>
        <option selected='selected' value=''>Bedrooms</option>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5 or more</option>
    </select>
</td>

PRICE;
}

echo $my_string;
?>
```

This seems to work really well in FF, Safari and Chrome just not in IE, I have seen similar problems but nothing that could solve this specific problem.

Any help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is so inefficient as it can be. Please load jQuery and use that plus JSON. Do not attempt to load table row's innerhtml. It is just not cross browser

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the problem is I don't have much experience with JQuery and JSON, perhaps I will look into that.  I have solved the problem and as you say trying to load table row inner html is a problem for Internet Explorer.  I have just placed the whole table inside a div and written to the div inner html. Probably not the most efficient or elegant solution but perhaps a short term fix until I master JQuery and JSON.  :)

Comment: Looking again, I see it is such a tiny difference. I suggest you load both sets and switch between them by hiding or displaying:
`function showPrice(letOrSale) { 
var forSale = letOrSale==="for_sale";
document.getElementById('forLetId').style.display=forSale?"none":"";
document.getElementById('forSaleId').style.display=forSale?"":"none";

}`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my problem and come up with a solution it is excellent! I was getting a slight problem with both sets loading by default but I solved this by calling the function with the <body onload="showPrice('for_sale')">... really excellent solution thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting comment to answer:

I suggest you load both sets and switch between them by hiding or displaying:

```
window.onload=function() {
  showPrice('for_sale'); // or do this in CSS
}
function showPrice(letOrSale) { 
  var forSale = letOrSale==="for_sale";
  document.getElementById('forLetId').style.display=forSale?"none":"";
  document.getElementById('forSaleId').style.display=forSale?"":"none"; 
}
```